# can xlock screenlock work with good color custom images?

Tags: linux, screen-lock

XLock version xlockmore-5.68 (latest from my distro)

I am trying to get xlock to show an image of my choosing. I took the code from https://powered-by-caffeine.blogspot.com/2012/09/show-single-image-with-xlock.html

Note, xlock does NOT do scaling, and so you must make sure the target fits within your screen, or else I found xlock to fail silently. Raster files `.ras` can have up to 8-bit color; I could not get color to work on anything else. For a 1600x900 monitor, I finally found the following to display my image, though without color or even a nice grayscale:

`convert -scale 800x600 globe.jpg globe.xbm`

```bash
xlock -mode image -visual default -bitmap /home/tardis/Wallpapers/globe.xbm -count 1 -lockdelay 15
```

Xsreensaver is comparatively gorgeous, but for technical reasons cannot lock the screen on my guix linux. I just hope to get xlock to be a little less visually jarring.

Is there a way to get xlock to display my image nicely and with color?